# Render bitmap to SpriteBatch in DirectXTK

Tags: graphics, directx, windows-phone-8

I need to port some C++ application to Windows Phone 8 (it is already on Android, iOS, WinCE and Win32). Currently I need to solving how to display graphic. I can get rendered bitmap from core application and I after succesfully initialize DirectXTK I'm able to render some DDS texture (DirectXTK::SpriteBatch). Now I need to transform my bitmap to texture and then render it. Can you help me with this out? Or is there some way to put bitmap directly to backbuffer and show it on display without SpriteBatch?

Thank you very much

Tomas

Answer (score 0):

DirectX toolkit has WICTextureLoader. You can use it instead of DDSTextureLoader for loading .bmp(bitmap) file. Hope this help!

http://directxtk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WICTextureLoader&referringTitle=DirectXTK

Comment: WicTextureLoader can't be used on Windows Phone 8

Comment: Source re: WIC being unsupported on Windows Phone 8 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662930(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: Note that WICTextureLoader is supported on Windows Phone 8.1

Answer (score 0):

Since WICTextureLoader is not supported on Windows Phone 8 the only way to render a bitmap to a texture is by mapping the texture to the CPU and copy your bitmap resource onto the mapped texture's resource.

ID3D11DeviceContext::Map()
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476457(v=vs.85).aspx

```
D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE mappedBuffer;
HRESULT hr = pContext->Map(pTexture, 0, D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD, 0, &mappedBuffer);

if(hr == S_OK)
{
    // copy your bitmap onto mappedBuffer.pData
    ...

    pContext->Unmap(pTex, 0);
}
```